Запятая перед деепричастием
Учиться возможно лишь совершая ошибки.
Нужна ли запятая перед "лишь"?

Правильно:
Учиться возможно / лишь совершая ошИбки.
Пояснение
Деепричастный оборот с обстоятельственным значение наречия (учиться на своих ошибках) не обособляется.
Пауза произносительная, одно ударение в конце предложения. Для сравнения: при обособлении делается два ударения (на сказуемом и не обороте).
